# Edit Mode in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

So i've implemented the

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but how will i trigger something to switch the tableview to edit mode? like the messages in iphone when you click edit, the delete icons appear. this might sound very basic but i'm getting no clue over this and its a little urgent, any clue will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! :) Thanks Alot!! I'm so happy for the quick & correct response. Best Wishes!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a navigation controller and load your table view in there. Then just assign an edit button to the left navigation bar item and it will toggle editing for you.

```
// in the table viewDidLoad

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```